# Iterating through Seq[row] till a particular condition is met using Scala

Tags: scala, loops, apache-spark, seq

I need to iterate a `scala` `Seq` of `Row` type until a particular condition is met. i dont need to process further post the condition.

I have a `seq[Row]` `r`->`WrappedArray([1/1/2020,abc,1],[1/2/2020,pqr,1],[1/3/2020,stu,0],[1/4/2020,opq,1],[1/6/2020,lmn,0])`

I want to iterate through this collection for `r.getInt(2)` until i encounter `0`. As soon as i encounter `0`, i need to break the iteration and collect `r.getString(1)` till then. I dont need to look into any other data post that.

My output should be: `Array(abc,pqr,stu)`

I am new to scala programming. This `seq` was actually a `Dataframe`. I know how to handle this using Spark `dataframes`, but due to some restriction put forth by my organization, `windows` function, `createDataFrame` function are not available/working in our environment. Hence i have resort to `Scala` programming to achieve the same.

All I could come up was something like below, but not really working!

```
breakable{
for(i <- r)
var temp = i.getInt(3)===0
if(temp ==true)
{
val = i.getInt(2)
break()
}
}
```

Can someone please help me here!

Comment: Working with time series without window functions... a really interesting company to work in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `takeWhile` method to grab the elements while it's value is 1

```
s.takeWhile(_.getInt(2) == 1).map(_.getString(1))
```

Than will give you

```
List(abc, pqr)
```

So you still need to get the first element where the int values 0 which you can do as follows:

```
s.find(_.getInt(2)== 0).map(_.getString(1)).get
```

Putting all together (and handle possible nil values):

```
s.takeWhile(_.getInt(2) == 1).map(_.getString(1)) ++ s.find(_.getInt(2)== 0).map(r => List(r.getString(1))).getOrElse(Nil)
```

**Result:**

```
Seq[String] = List(abc, pqr, stu)
```

Comment: the solution worked! thanks! just out of curiosity, is it possible to get the distinct records into list? something like collect_set()?

Comment: So you want a list of lists? Sorry if i didnt get it, please provide an example of whan you expect to obtain